# How to calculate throughput for individual links (there by fairness index) using old wireless trace format file in ns2?

Tags: awk, ns2

I am stuck as in how to identify the different connections(flows) in trace file.

Comment: This Q is very under-specified. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more questions here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the format in which the trace file is being created

```
event
time
Source node
Destination node
Packet type
Packet size
flags
fid
Source address
Dest. address
Seq. number
Packet id
```

If you take a look at the frame format of a trace file, the 8th column is the flow id which you can extract using an `awk`file.

Read more on `awk` file and how you can isolate or count sent and received packets along with flow id. Once you have that just divide the two.